# Unable to add disaster recovery property to vm module in azure bicep

Tags: azure-bicep

Iam Unable to add disaster recovery property to vm module in azure bicep.

```
disasterrecovery:[


recovery vault Name :myrsv

target availability set id : myavset

target resource group : mygroup

Cache storage account name : my storage 
]
```

Same like arm templates I mentioned. But it's throws error like template not valid.
Some one help to fix the issue

Comment: AFAIK It only supports in ARM template but not in bicep. @Satish B

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add disaster recovery properties in existing VM module in azure Bicep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76962189/how-to-add-disaster-recovery-properties-in-existing-vm-module-in-azure-bicep)

Answer (score 0):

For virtual machine resources, Bicep does not include a `disasterRecovery` function. It allows you to define virtual machines and their related properties, but it does not allow to add `disasterrecovery` configurations at the virtual machine level directly.
Rather bicep supports virtual machine backup functionality only.

After a workaround on your issue, I found an alternative approach as follows.

You can create a custom [deployment script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deployment-script-bicep#sample-bicep-files) in bicep and pass the [site recovery PowerShell script](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/site-recovery/azure-to-azure-powershell.md#create-a-site-recovery-fabric-object-to-represent-the-recovery-region) in `scriptcontent{}` block as detailed in the MS Doc.

By referring to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/quick-backup-vm-bicep-template) template, I tried creating a backup for VM and was able to deploy it successfully.

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

[image]

[image]